# Summernote JS - Inject code & parameters in the same initialization

Tags: javascript, meteor, summernote

how to inject `code` in the initialization parameters?
In other words, how to merge those two pieces of code (both working fine) below?
Thanks

```
var titleformodif = 'bob';

// initialization #1
$('#tasktitle_modify').summernote('code', titleformodif);

// initialization #2
$('.tasktitle_modify').summernote({
    //insert code here
    airMode: true,
    placeholder: 'in few words',
    dialogsInBody: true,
    disableDragAndDrop: true,
    popover: {
    link: [
        ['link', ['linkDialogShow', 'unlink']]
    ],
    air: [
        ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol']],
        ['insert', ['link']]
    ]
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, at least there is no `code` (or equivalent) option you can provide. However, you can set the code in a callback, such as the `onInit` callback, which *is* an option:

```
$('.tasktitle_modify').summernote({
    //insert code here
    callbacks: {
        onInit: function() {
            $(this).summernote('code', titleformodif);
        }
    },
    airMode: true,
    // ...etc...
});
```

Comment: My mistake: it's working fine, I forget to use `$(this)` in the callback. Thanks for taking time for me.